# CSS transitions - Switching between fixed and absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, transition

I'll try to explain a big problem that has me stumped.

Basically, I have a #menu that goes between absolute positioned(when close to the top of the page) and fixed positioned(to the top of the window, when scrolling down the page). I'm using jquery to accomplish this.

When it gets fixed, I give it a ".fixed" class. Which gives it "top:0px;position:relative;". #menu has a transition to it, but #menu.fixed removes the transition. This works great in the beginning, when scrolling down and then having it become attached to the top of the window. Switching the positions is flawless as the new class has the transitions removed.

However, when I scroll back up, and it removes the ".fixed" class, it animates the (now) absolutely positioned #menu from 0px to 615px. Which means it jumps up to the top of the page, and then scrolls down, as it's not fixed anymore.

This is the code:

```
$('#menu').css({ top: '615px'}); // top was 0px before this. It is still fixed, so it should NOT animated.
$('#menu').removeClass('fixed'); // Now the transition kicks in
//As it's at 615px, it should stay where it is, not start animating to 615px from 0px as it does.
```

I think it's because the element hasn't actually been repositioned by the time the ".fixed" class is removed, and thus it animates down with it's new positioning... I could do an interval or something similar to trigger the class to be removed, but it just seems silly.

I'm also aware that I could just make it positioned:absolutely all the time. And just reposition the top-value when I scroll. But that seems redundant...

Does anyone know how to solve my problem?

Comment: can we see it somewhere, so we can better understand the problem ?

Comment: I've put up a test link here, where the problem can be viewed. Try scrolling down until the menu attaches itself, and then scrolling back up: http://www.chrislind.se/transition_test/

Comment: Ok, i see what you mean.. I do not understand, though, why you have added the transition. It only adds the problem. If you remove the transition it works fine (*and it doesn't seem to be used anywhere else*).

Comment: I've added the transition because if you try and click on the black button while it's "absolute", it needs to be able to open, yet still being able to be stuck to the bottom of the top image.

Comment: There's a lot of stray tags like `</header>` and `</section>` that may be complicating things.  I'd run this through the [W3C markup validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and follow its suggestions; it might be of some help.

Comment: CSS `transition: none;`